# Javascript make a function only work once

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr

I'm working on a blog theme where you can like posts from the theme page. It uses the following javascript to like the post with the tumblr API, change the white heart to a red heart, and also +1 to the post note count, displayed above the like buttons. It works fine, but I have the problem that when you click the heart button, it turns red, likes the post, and +1's to the note count, but you can continue to click the button once it's already liked and it keeps adding one to the note count. Can anyone help me to make it so it's a function that only works once, ex: someone clicks the heart button, it turns red, adds one to the note count, and then is done.

```
$(function() {    
        $('.likepost').live('click', function() {
            var post = $(this).closest('article');
            var id = post.attr('id');
            var oauth = post.attr('rel').slice(-8);
            var count = parseInt($("#note_count_"+ id).text());
            var like = 'http://www.tumblr.com/like/'+oauth+'?id='+id;
            $('#like-it').attr('src', like);
            $(this).css({"background" : "url(http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/JYdlzwvnx/like2.png)"});
            $("#note_count_"+ id).text(count+1);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

It's functioning on http://blog.jamescharless.com/,  by the way. You have to be logged into tumblr for the script to work.

Comment: I think the problem here is not that it works more than once, but that it is not being associated with the tumblr account. Otherwise, the user can just refresh the page and like it a second time.

Comment: @canon - read http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("body").one("click", ".likepost", function() {
//your code here
});
```

By using the [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function you only allow the click to be triggered one time. It's kind of what it was designed for. Ideally you'd want to use a parent of .likepost closer to it than the body, but worst case you could just use body as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You can [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click event.

```
$(function() {    
        $('.likepost').live('click', function() {
            var post = $(this).closest('article');
            var id = post.attr('id');
            var oauth = post.attr('rel').slice(-8);
            var count = parseInt($("#note_count_"+ id).text());
            var like = 'http://www.tumblr.com/like/'+oauth+'?id='+id;
            $('#like-it').attr('src', like);
            $(this).css({"background" : "url(http://static.tumblr.com/uiqhh9x/JYdlzwvnx/like2.png)"});
            $("#note_count_"+ id).text(count+1);

            // unbind
            $(this).unbind('click');

            return false;
      });
});
```

Comment: How would I do that? I'm not very good with javascript at all.

Comment: @Zhihao Your theory is partially right, it's actually impossible to tell whether a user likes a post or not, i think. But it does work more than once..

Comment: Just like this. Don't be afraid to read jQuery's doc. It is full of examples.

Comment: @JamesCharless Sorry, I moved my comment to the question since it wasn't specific to this answer. I don't have experience with tumblr or the API, but do they not provide a method to like something as a user (and return a success indicator), or otherwise retrieve the number of likes? That is, assuming the like feature is provided by tumblr. To be clear, I'm referring to an AJAX request and not something done purely on the client side.